# LaTeX code was abbreviatedly displaied by Vimwiki in Vim

Tags: vim, latex, vim-plugin

[My GVim distribution](https://github.com/llinfeng/vim) on a Windows 8.1 machine has both [`vimwiki`](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki) and [`Vim-Latex-Suite`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vim-latex/) installed through [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim).

It bothers me that the following display (on the left) will occur when I do the following:

1. Open a `*.wiki` file (thereby enter the `filetype vimwiki` once);
2. In the same GVim session, open another `*.tex` file.

[image]

Notice that almost all those math symbols are no longer readable on the left. The quoted code-segment was displayed correctly (on the right) when opened by itself, through a new `Gvim.exe` session.

For this specific case, my guess is that, Vim is incapable of:

1. Correctly identify and display all math symbols (e.g. subscripts are displayed as a square);
2. Correctly displaying math symbols in full-width. (By default, half-width is default and this is why those `\phi` or `\int` are hiding all its right part.)

The goal for this post is not to "display math symbols in Vim" correctly. It is too wild and [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/) can handle it pretty well. **Instead, I would like to know**:

- **How can I stop Vimwiki from interfering the display of `*.tex`
  documents?**

Any suggestion? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Original answer from @Sato Katsura

This is the `conceal` feature. It works better in gVim, provided that you use a font that has all the relevant symbols. You can disable it with:

```
set conceallevel=0
```

## Further details for Vimwiki

Vimwiki has specified `g:vimwiki_conceallevel=2` by default according to line 2100 of the [help file](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/blob/master/doc/vimwiki.txt). Unfortunately, this "default value" was set globally for all buffers.

## Specific solution:

- For `~\vimfiles\ftplugin\tex.vim`, add the following to the end:

  setlocal conceallevel=0
- For `~\vimfiles\ftplugin\vimwiki.vim`, add the following to the end:

  setlocal conceallevel=2

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem what made me research until reach this mapping:

```
 nnoremap <Leader>c :let &cole=(&cole == 2) ? 0 : 2 <bar> echo 'conceallevel ' . &cole <CR>
```

It toggles between `conceallevel=0` to `conceallevel=2`